# Is ConcurrentQueue the best way to offload logging from ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net, logging, concurrency, message-queue

I have an ASP.NET MVC-application which relies heavily on event-logging, which is done synchronously to SQL Server. During heavy load and with the amount of logs, I need to off load the logging from the main-thread. **I was looking at `ConcurrentQueue`, is it the best way to off load logging från ASP.NET?**

I have looked into several options like using an external application working through the logs and inserting them to the database:

- Implementing a message queue with MSMQ

  - Too many messages might clog the queue, and we might never catch up inserting to database?
- Logging to text-files

  - Slow serializing and writing to disk(?)
  - Built in redundancy is a plus

Or making ASP.NET itself handle the inserting to database by logging to a `ConcurrentQueue`/`BlockingCollection` and

- Starting a long-running Task on "Startup" and checking the queue, using [this code from "learn-some-code"](https://github.com/learn-some-code/csharp-samples/blob/master/Logger/Logger.cs).

  - Quick and low footprint
  - What happens if the Task exits unexpectedly
  - ASP.NET not built for long running tasks(?)
- Configuring Hangfire or similar to check the queue

  - Dependency to the database

Comment: Seems to me that all of the approaches above suffer from the "Too many messages might clog the queue" problem. If you're approaching these sorts of limits, then tying the performance of any of your tiers to logging concerns is problematic. If I were butting up against these limits, I'd opt for a message queue and a (logging) consumer that can be scaled independently from any other part of the system.

Comment: *"I need to off load the logging from the main-thread"* <== do you mean that you want to do the logging in [fire-and-forget](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2014/06/fire-and-forget-on-asp-net.html) fashion, in other words serve the request now and log later?

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Yes, the client need no verification of that the logging has been performed. Thanks for the link.

Comment: @spender Thanks, I guess that would be the "safest" alternative, even though it adds complexity and external dependencies.

Comment: Have you exhaust all potential of tweaking the logging performance? It seems to me that if the logging has become the bottleneck of an application, something has really gone wrong.

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Good question. At the moment we are writing logs with Entity Framework, no async, multiple statements for each HTTP-request. I took this to heart (even if it targets .NET Core specifically):  "If your logging data store is slow, don't write to it directly. Consider writing the log messages to a fast store initially, then move them to the slow store later. For example, log to a message queue that's read and persisted to slow storage by another process." https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/11801

Comment: I've successfully used RabbitMQ for this purpose, it's designed to handle a lot of messages. Another process was listening to RabbitMQ queue and inserting logs into database over the time (though over the time those logs were archived from database to yet another persistent storage). That said - RabbitMQ was used also for other things in that project, not sure if using it _just_ for logging is a good idea... ConcurrentQueue has a drawback that it collects messages in the same process, so if it crashes - all logs in queue are lost (also it puts load on the same database and server as main app).